# Why does this code only show 1 ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, review

I am having a problem.
I know I am using deprecated MySQL, but I am working on a website for school and security is not necessary(as long as it works). I am trying to get all the Id's from a table called Reviews. This should be stored in a array. For some reason it only shows the first one. How to get all of them stored in 1 array? This is my code which is not working:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT Klanten_id FROM Reviews";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)['Klanten_id'];
```

Comment: RTM: [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php): _Fetch a result row as an associative array_. You need a loop (There is an exemple in the manual too).

Comment: But since we are at it, don't use outdated APIs, learn PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: How to use loop in a database then? That stores all id's in a array?

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples out there. Do we really need to provide another?

Comment: Btw guys, I am still learning and I find it very demotivating when people dislike the post. I am struggeling with this for a while, but it finally works now thanks to Alive to Die. Thanks for understanding and people trying to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Don't use outdated `mysql_*` library.Turn to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

2.[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php): Fetch a result row as an associative array. So you need to apply loop to get all data

Like below:-

```
$ids = array(); //created an array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
    $ids[] = $row['Klanten_id']; // assign each id to the array
}
print_r($ids);// print array
```

3.To start working on `mysqli/PDO` check basic example here:- [mysqli/PDO example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: I understand your answer, but how to split the id's. If I get id=1 and id=12. It echoes 121. I want it to be stored in a array like this: ("1","12")